# Can someone explain the time complexity between those two functions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, heap, dynamic-programming

Both the functions find the kth largest element from an array. The first one finds the largest using MinHeap while the second uses MaxHeap. Can someone explain the time complexity of both functions?

```
from heapq import heappop, heappush, heapify

def findKthLargest1(arr, k): #Using MinHeap
    minHeap = []

    for num in arr:
        heappush(minHeap, num)

        if len(minHeap) > k:    
            heappop(minHeap)    
    
    return minheap[0]           


def findKthLargest(arr,k):  #Using MaxHeap
    maxHeap = []

    for num in arr:                  
        heappush(maxHeap, num * -1)

    for i in range(k):
        sol = heappop(maxHeap) * -1

    return sol
```

Answer (score 1):

Both have `O(N)` space complexity because we create a new data structure heap

In both we are holding only "k" items in the heap and sorting only the k items. So both has

```
 T:O(k * log(k))
```

`log(k)` for partitioning

`k` is for comparison